# Python create n lists

Tags: python, list

I'd like to create a number of lists in function of the number of characters in a word. How it works:

I ask for a word; I get the length of the word; I check if the length of the word is odd or even by **comparing the remainder** of the division of the length by 2 **to 0**; If it is odd, I add a Z at the end of the word to make it even; If it isn't, the word doesn't change; Then, what I don't know how to do is how to separate this final word (that is even) into pairs of two characters, each contained in different lists.

```
word=input("Enter word")

wordlenght= len(word)

remainder= wordlenght%2

if remainder==0:
        finalword=word
else:
        finalword= word+"z"

 lenghtoffinalword= len(finalword)
 numberoflists= lenghtoffinalword/2
```

The above code works; I end up with the final word I'd like to separate into pairs that will each be stored in different lists and the number of lists necessary. What I don't get is how I can create a varying amount of lists and insert in each one of them a portion of my word.

Any help would be very appreciated. 
Thanks :)

Comment: So use a list of lists or a dictionary of lists. Don't try to generate separate variables.